# Search terms that include accented characters

Tags: support, search, spelling, internationalization

How do I search for questions & answers using a keyword that includes an accented character. For example, I often look at questions about Bezier curves. Some people spell Bezier correctly, with an acute accent on the first "e". If I just search for "Bezier" (with no accent) I don't find these questions.

Comment: Instead of the broken beast on SE, use a real searcher like google `Bézier site:stackexchange.com`

Comment: The issue you mention has actually been fixed, I just tested again myself. The difference is that if you search for "Bézier", then posts containing the accented version will come first, while if you search for "Bezier" posts with the unaccented version will come first. But the set of results is the same in both cases. (Some users apparently believe that different spellings are interchangeable and purposefully butcher names, so I wouldn't expect the overall issue to change soon.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The preference for the exact search term over variants only really exists when sorted by "relevance" (the default). When sorted by, for instance, votes, the mixture is more readily visible: [search for `Bézier`](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=B%C3%A9zier%20) vs. [search for `Bezier`](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Bezier%20), sorted by votes.  (Although, strangely, occurences of "Bézier" in the `Bezier` search are not highlighted in the results.)

Comment: Y'all are quite correct. When I search for "Bezier", I rarely see any results that contain "Bézier", and this led me to believe that there was a problem with the search function. But, in fact, the reason I rarely see "Bézier" is that people rarely spell the gentleman's name correctly.

Comment: @achillehui -- good idea, but Google doesn't work where I live (China).

Comment: @bubba the same command works on baidu. Not sure how good it is but I silently suspect it is smarter than one used by SE.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In my opinion, not using a character that doesn't exist in the language isn't "butchering" a name. (Besides that, for example I have an American keyboard with no numpad, so I would have to copy and paste from the character map every time I wanted to use an accented character.)

Comment: @Matt Yes, it is... Using a different letter *is* butchering. Italian doesn't have the letter 'y', for example, they didn't start spelling the name as "Cauchi". I think there's a difference between wanting people to write "Poincaré" and wanting people to write "Чебышёв" (Chebyshev)... I understand that some people have technical difficulties, but if you've shown that you're able to type the correct name and you don't, it's laziness and not respectful.

Comment: I happen to know that the family of the late Pierre Bézier get quite upset when people spell his name incorrectly. I gripe at people about this from time to time, but it seems like a never-ending up-hill struggle.